# Which version of OpenGL does Intel's integrated graphics card support?

Tags: drivers, opengl, version, intel-graphics, ultrabook

Many ultrabooks make use of the *Intel HD Integrated Graphics 4000* chips which are part of the CPU. My question is which OpenGL version do they support with the newest drivers?

I would like to know the major and minor version number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Comparison of Intel graphics processing units # 7th generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units#Seventh_generation), the Intel HD Graphics 4000 supports OpenGL up to version:

- 4.0 on Windows
- 4.1 on MacOS X
- 4.2 on Linux (since Mesa 17.1)

Answer (score 1):

Intel HD 4000 for the Macs;

- 3.2 on OS X 10.8 due to limitation of operating system GL driver support.
- 4.1 on OS X 10.9. Apple started to ship 4.x drivers from 10.9.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/GLInfo_1085_Core.html) for complete table. Wikipedia page seems to be not yet updated.